# numpy masked_array mask changes type

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I am a bit surprised by the fact that `np.ma.masked_equal` or `masked_values` does not create a mask of False if the value is not in the array, but instead a scalar.

Example :

```
y = np.arange(10)
yy = np.ma.masked_equal(y,0)
```

yields a masked array withe the mask being an array of 10 False values, while

```
y = np.arange(1,10) 
yy = np.ma.masked_equal(y,0)
```

yields a masked array with the mask set to the scalar False. As a result, given that in my code I do not know beforehand whether the mask match any entry in the array, I am forced to check explicitly:

```
yy=np.ma.masked_values(y,0)
if np.isscalar(yy.mask):
    yy.mask=np.zeros(y.shape,dtype=bool)
```

This seems an overwork to me. What is the reason for this behavior, and is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create the `MaskedArray` youself:

```
yy = np.ma.MaskedArray(y, mask=(y==0))
```

It seems that NumPy tries to minimize the memory requirements and speed up the computations in case the `MaskedArray` is unmasked.

> **numpy.ma.nomask**
>
> Value indicating that a masked array has no invalid entry. `nomask` is used internally to speed up computations when the mask is not needed.

If you check:

```
>>> np.ma.nomask
False
```

So the single `False` represents "no mask". So you could also check `maskedarr.mask is np.ma.nomask` (it's a [garantueed constant](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#constants-of-the-numpy-ma-module)):

```
yy = some_operation_that_creates_a_masked_array
if yy.mask is np.ma.nomask:
    yy.mask = np.zeros(yy.shape, dtype=bool)
```

That carries a bit more context then `np.isscalar`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I guess it makes sense, and I was probably too keen on using masked_equal or masked_values, but I am not sure I understand why it is in the context of their use that numpy tries to minimize memory requirements, and not when creating the masked_array directly.